# GoogleCast iOS sender, v4, not sending messages

Tags: swift, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

On version 2, the sender app was able to send messages.

```
func deviceManager(_ deviceManager: GCKDeviceManager!,
didConnectToCastApplication
applicationMetadata: GCKApplicationMetadata!,
sessionID: String!,
launchedApplication: Bool) {
  deviceManager.add(self.textChannel)
}
```

However, the API says that we are now using GCKSessionManager instead of GCKDeviceManager.

The API says I must have a GCKSession add the textChannel, which I did here:
Once the session starts, I add the textChannel (because sessionManager.currentCastSession was nil before the session started).

```
func sessionManager(_ sessionManager: GCKSessionManager, didStart session: GCKSession) {
    if session.device == connectionQueue {
        connectionQueue = nil
    }
    self.sessionManager!.currentCastSession!.add(textChannel)
    print("")
}
```

Meanwhile, I send the text message in another function:

```
let result = self.textChannel.sendTextMessage("\(self.textField.text)", error: &error)
```

But the result is always false, and the error is always "Channel is not connected or is not registered with a session".
In addition, when I do:

```
print("isConnected1 \(self.textChannel.isConnected)")
```

the result is false.
Do you know what other steps I am missing for it to be connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just learned that it was an issue of my namespace. It connects now.
Problem was the namespace wasn't matching the namespace from my receiver code.

```
fileprivate lazy var textChannel:TextChannel = {
return TextChannel(namespace: NAMESPACE)
}()
```

Comment: Hi, I encounter the same issue, how do you get the namespace of currentCastSession so that it will match?

Comment: Looks like in my index.html for my receiver app, I had this line:
window.messageBus =
          window.castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus(
              NAMESPACE);

Comment: Also, the generic namespace name is 'urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.sample.helloworld'

Comment: is the generic namespace always like that?

Comment: Not sure but I guess it is that way, and that default receivers have that set as their namespace